# java dynamic proxy issue

Tags: java, proxy

I'm learning about java dynamic proxy, and here's my code:

```
//interface  Move.java
 public interface Move {
    public void testMove();
}
```

then the implementation class

```
public class Tank implements Move{
    public void testMove() {
        System.out.println("test in Tank");
    }
}
```

followed by

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;


public class MoveHandler implements InvocationHandler{
    private Object target;

    public MoveHandler(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
                    throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("in MoveHandler");
        Object ret;
        try {
            ret = method.invoke(target, args);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        System.out.println("after MoveHandler");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

test class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Move test = new Tank();
        MoveHandler proxy = new MoveHandler(test);
        Move real = (Move) Proxy.newProxyInstance(test.getClass().getClassLoader(), test.getClass().getInterfaces(), proxy);
        real.testMove();
    }
}
```

I can get the right result when I run the Main class. If I change `method.invoke(target, args)` into `method.invoke(proxy, args)`, there will be thousand lines of exception and errors. What's the usage of the argument **proxy** in `invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)` and how can I use it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

The proxy argument is the object returned by `Proxy.newProxyInstance()`, on which the actual method (`testMove()`) is called. You usually don't need it, but it can be necessary to know which interfaces the proxy implements, for example.

Invoking the method on this argument is a really bad idea since it basically does a recursive method call : you invoke a method on a proxy, which calls the invocation handler, which calls the method on the proxy, which calls the handler, etc.

Comment: Is it means the argument proxy represents the proxy object, but not the proxyed one?

Comment: Yes. proxy is... the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

> Using Java Reflection you create dynamic implementations of interfaces at runtime. You do so using the class `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. The name of this class is why I refer to these dynamic interface implementations as dynamic proxies. Dynamic proxies can be used for many different purposes, e.g. database connection and transaction management, dynamic mock objects for unit testing, and other AOP-like method intercepting purposes.

Further explanation:

> The `proxy` parameter passed to the `invoke()` method is the dynamic proxy object implementing the interface. Most often you don't need this object.

This is from [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html), which explains in a lot more detail.